# Java Why is this giving me "0"?

Tags: java, class, math, printing, output

So this is a portion of the code I'm using, we were only supposed to begin by fixing some logical errors because of wrong answers.  I found a couple of syntax errors as well that wouldn't let the compiler finish up...I keep getting "0" for fToC...

```
//declaration statements
final int BOILING_IN_F = 212;
int fToC;
string output;

//there is other code between that has nothing
//to do with outputting the boiling point.

fToC = (5/9) * (BOILING_IN_F - 32);
output = BOILING_IN_F + " in Fahrenheit is " + fToC
             + " in Celsius.";
System.out.println(output); //this is outputting 0 for fToC
System.out.println();
```

Answers were useful, except I needed to declare fToC as a double before compiling and running the program.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it was something like that.  I was mixing up some Python I learned last semester when trying to change the formula up.  I appreciate the help, I'm pretty upset at myself for not seeing this.  But life goes on.

Comment: I also realized that I needed to declare fToC as a double.  After some reading in my text, I noticed that Java will not permit the assignment of what could be a double to an int because of a possible loss of data.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing Java's integer division with `5/9`, which must result in another integer -- `0`, so the result is `0`.  Use `double` literals to force floating-point math.

```
fToC = (5.0/9.0) * (BOILING_IN_F - 32);
```

You'll need `fToC` to be a `double` (and change the typo `string output` to be `String output`).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to change int fToC to double fToC?

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi Correct; updated.

Answer (score 1):

`(5/9)` is 0 due to int division. Try `(5.0/9)`

The full expression should be :

```
fToC = (5.0/9) * (BOILING_IN_F - 32);
```

Answer (score 1):

`(5/9)` You're diving two integers, so this is truncated, so it equals 0. And you're multiplying that 0 with another number.

Use instead `(5.0f/9.0f)` to precise the fact that your number are actually decimal numbers.